# How do I install a Linux OS on a Windows 10 OS for mutli-boot startup

Tags: installation, multi-boot

How do you do install a Linux operating system {http://www.ubuntu.com/} on a Gateway NE56R laptop. {http://panam.gateway.com/s/notebook/2012/Gateway/NE/NE56R/NE56Rsp2.shtml} running Windows 10. The laptop was recently restored back to factory settings and has 285 gigs of memory free. I have partitioned 80 gigs on my disk drive but am unsure how I label the disk space so the new OS can be put there. I would like to do a dual boot. I have never used a Linux OS and want to keep both OS's until I am familiar with it. I haven't been able to find much on Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot setup online. Please let me know if more information is needed to answer this question on my end.

Comment: Don't do that - this site actually is super useful. Some patrons are just not very skilled communicators. Downvoting is fine but there needs to be a reason I think. Wrt. to your question, as noted in the answer below, modern Ubuntu (others too I am sure) installers will detect and not wreck your Windows installation. Do make a `wbadmin` backup of your Windows setup to some other device - just to be safe.

Comment: When I went to open the OS downloaded file I was not able to. It is labeled as an image file? I'm not sure how to open it  or what to open it with. I am just being careful because this is my first time loading and operating system on to a computer. If I mess this up it could hurt my OS and laptops don't come with startup disk these days. If being careful makes me stupid I can live with that but it never hurts to ask a question when your not sure...I guess it does on this site. Mrmajestyk

Comment: You need to make a bootable medium containing all the files in the image you downloaded. In Windows 10, you can just double click the image - it then becomes a virtual DVD drive. Then get a USB stick, format it and copy everything from the virtual DVD onto it. Then try booting your laptop with the stick in a USB port. You may need to select which medium to boot from as your laptop boots (press F6 or something). On older machines, you may need more steps. Try googling 'ubuntu bios boot install'. Or try the Rufus tool (google that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guide is the official one from Ubuntu I think. It details some pitfalls and considerations you need to have in place before you proceed. Have a look at that fine piece of documentation [right here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) - and *do* make a backup first. You can use `wbadmin` that comes with Windows to create a backup from a command prompt with administrator privileges:

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:<your backup drive or share> -include:<your Windows drive (C:)> -allCritical
```

Details by MS are available [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There are hundreds of step-by-step guides on how to dual-boot a Windows OS with a Linux OS.

You don't need to label the partition.

The Ubuntu installer should automatically identify that Windows 10 is installed on your computer already and, when GRUB2 (the Linux bootloader) is installed to the start of the disk, will create a menu where you can choose which OS to boot from whenever you start your computer.

Comment: Sorry to have come across as demeaning, this is not my intention, however having a quick Google of how to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu there are many people who have done this successfully and they have documented this in great detail. Your question doesn't give any specific detail as to what you've tried so far and whether a problem has been identified that's not letting you complete your installation. The question comes across as asking for someone here to provide a step-by-step as to how to dual-boot your chosen OSes.

Comment: Well my first question asked on this site was choped down to 1 10th the starting size and edited so much I thought that being short precise and to the point was how you were supposed to propose your query. I am aware that this is not something considered a "superuser" deep research needed question overall. There were just a few fine points I was hoping to get a better understanding on before I proceed with my first OS install. So doing 1 with 2 different OS's and dual startup I thought I could tap this outlet for a few quick ?'s. That's why I made it short and to the point. Bigchris